# Bitbucket pipeline AWS script to send sqs message failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket pipeline that builds and then sends a message to SQS. The pipeline builds then fails at my sendsqsreq.sh with the error code `./scripts/sendsqsreq.sh: line 14: aws: command not found` see screen shot below:

[image]

The code for the script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit upon encountering an error
set -euo pipefail

# Set the base route
ROOT_DIR=$(pwd)

# Run the script to set up the env variables and other custom functions
source $ROOT_DIR/scripts/utilis.sh

sendsqsrequest(){
  info "sending sqs request"
  is_success_or_fail $(aws sqs send-message --queue-url $QUEUEURL --message-body "bitbukcet manualrun trigger" --region=$AWS_REGION)
}
main () {
    sendsqsrequest
}

main
```

Line 14 is `is_success_or_fail $(aws sqs send-message --queue-url $QUEUEURL --message-body "bitbukcet manualrun trigger" --region=$AWS_REGION)`

I'm not sure what command I'm missing.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have to change this line in the pipeline: `export PATH=~/bin:$PATH` to `export PATH=~/bin/aws:$PATH`